# Is there a way to monitor the different subtensors of a custom Keras backend loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, loss-function

I'm currently implementing a custom loss function by modelling it as a Keras backend tensor. The loss function has different parts (such as a classification loss, a quantization loss or a pairwise distance loss)

The code looks something like this:

```
...
different_class_loss = K.log(1 + K.exp(-1*dissimilarity + margin))
pair_loss = same_class * same_class_loss   +   (1-same_class) * different_class_loss

loss_value = lambda_pair * pair_loss + lambda_classif * classif_loss + lambda_quant_binary * quantization_loss

# Add loss to model
pairwise_model.add_loss(loss_value)

# Compile without specifying a loss
pairwise_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer_adam)
```

When I train the model using a batch_generator and pairwise_model.fit() the history contains exactly one loss argument for the combined loss_value. For debugging purposes I'd like to monitor every part of that loss function individually (i.e .quantization, classification and pairwise distance loss), but I can't figure out how.

I tried implementing a callback using K.eval() or K.print_tensor() to retrieve the values during training, but that didn't work. I also wasn't able to add multiple loss metrics using the add_loss function.

Is there a way to do this without writing a custom training loop? It feels like there should be. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**__________________________________________________**

**EDIT:**

Following the idea from Dr. Snoopy, here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
...
different_class_loss = K.log(1 + K.exp(-1*dissimilarity + margin))
pair_loss = same_class * same_class_loss   +   (1-same_class) * different_class_loss

loss_value = lambda_pair * pair_loss + lambda_classif * classif_loss + lambda_quant_binary * quantization_loss

# Add loss to model
pairwise_model.add_loss(loss_value)

# Add additional losses as metrics
pairwise_model.add_metric(pair_loss, name = "pairwise loss")
pairwise_model.add_metric(quantization_loss, name = "quantization loss")

# Compile without specifying a loss or metrics
pairwise_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer_adam)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass them as metrics, like this:

```
def pl():
    return pair_loss

pairwise_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer_adam, metrics=[pl])
```

And you can do similarly for your other loss components. The function might not be needed, you could also try passing `pair_loss` directly as a metric.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Just one small correction: Apparently you can't add these as metrics using the argument of compile(), but instead you have add them in same way I added the loss:
pairwise_model.add_metric(pair_loss, name = "pairwise loss"), calling compile without a metrics argument afterwards

Comment: @Jonas This works for me in Keras 2.3 and 2.2, maybe it was changed in tf.keras or future releases.

Comment: Oh, that might be it. I am using "from tensorflow import keras". I believe I had to change it to that because just using "import keras" gave me an error message at some point and this was a suggested fix. But I don't quite remember. I will test this out later today.